# Moving textFile from one class to autofill a textarea in another

Tags: text, netbeans, autofill

```
private void ManausActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
  Cities cities=new Cities();
    cities.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();

    c.getSites("Manaus.txt");
    c.getRestaraunt("Rio.txt");
     cArray[0]=c;
```

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
So what i want to do is from my GUI on this button press these text files sent another Gui where its text fields will be Auto-Filled with the data and there will be other buttons and cites. its all in an object Array any help much appreciated.